# notifyDataSetChanged crashing the application

Tags: android

Could someone explain me where  the following problem is coming from:

I have a list that displays several items according to some preferences . The user can change these preferences through a SlidingDrawer . Whenever this happens I get the items corresponding to the new preferences and then I the set the result to the adapter backing the listview with the code below.

```
 public void update(final List<Report> reports)
 {
       adapter.setReports(reports);
       ((ArrayAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
       list.invalidate();
 }
```

Here's the adapter class

```
public class ReportsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Report>
{
    List<Report> reports;
    Activity context;

    public void setReports(List<Report> reports)
    {
        this.reports = reports;
    }

    ReportsAdapter(Activity context, List<Report> reports)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.row_report, R.id.report_timestamp,reports) ;

        this.reports = reports;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.row_report, null);

        TextView timestamp = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.report_timestamp);
        if(timestamp != null)
            timestamp.setText("Timestamp: "+reports.get(position).getTimestamp());

        TextView type = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.report_type);
        if(type != null)
            type.setText("Type: "+reports.get(position).getReportType().getType().toString());

        TextView status = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.report_status);
        if(status != null)
           status.setText("Status: "+reports.get(position).getStatus());

        ImageView icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.report_icon);
        if(icon != null && reports.get(position).getReportType().getType()!= ReportType.RType.DEFAULT)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), reports.get(position).getIconResource());
            if(bitmap != null)
            {
                icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }        
        return row;
    }
}
```

After that the application crashes  with an ArrayOutOfBoundsException in the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm what does your custom Adapter extend from? You're probably not updating the same Array/List that the `getCount()` is getting its size from. Or maybe there's another problem with your `getCount()` implementation. I've found through practice that the safest way to get an Adapter working properly is to just extend from `BaseAdapter` and fill in any of the methods that the compiler asks you to.

Incidentally, you don't have to get the adapter through the list (since it's the same as `adapter`, hopefully), so you can do `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` directly.

If this doesn't solve your problem, consider posting your adapter code.

Comment: Yep, as I suspected. The problem is that the `getCount()` is based on the *original* size of the array you initialized the adapter with (see [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)), you can override it but, like I said, it will be easier if you just extend from `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that the internal reference to the backed data is never modified after initialization